# How do I include "two characters", whether its two numbers, or two letters, or a combination of them in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Here's what I'm trying to do: I am using the google maps API to create a map with a bunch of different markers and on each marker, I want a letter.

I have all the markers set up, but I have 31 markers. There are only 26 letters in the alphabet, so once it hits Z, it goes back to A. Another solution is to figure out how to use numbers, but after I get to 9, I can't do 10 -- because the for loop only slices off one character at a time.

Here's the code I have:

```
// These are the labels for the markers
const labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let labelIndex = 0;
```

```
for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),


// THIS IS THE LINE IM TALKING ABOUT vvvvvvvvvvvvv

label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],

// THIS IS THE LINE IM TALKING ABOUT ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


map: map,
});
```

So as you can see, I want to be able to use double digits as well -- but with this current setup I cannot do that. I hope this is enough info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change labels to an array of valid labels, if all you need is just go beyond A-Z but are still dealing with a fixed maximum amount of labels. If you need an infinite number of labels, we'd need to take a different approach that I'm not attempting here unless you confirm with a comment that that's what you need.

As for fixed number, you could specify each one:

```js
const labels = ["A", "B", "C", .... "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", ...]
```

etc.

If you wanted to, you could generate a *lot* of labels, but still a fixed amount. Here's an example that generates 702 labels:

```js
const __labels = Array.from("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
const labels = __labels.concat(__labels.map(c1 => __labels.map(c2 => c1+c2)).flat())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is also one possible solution, you can increase the number of the distinct  `label` by increasing the size of  `label`.

Here we are using `Set` to make sure that `label` created is unique

The solution given by Patrick is very elegant too.

```js
const labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let set = new Set();

function randomString() {
  return (
    labels[Math.floor(Math.random() * labels.length)] +
    labels[Math.floor(Math.random() * labels.length)]
  );
}

function generateRandomLabel() {
  let label = randomString();
  while (!set.add(label)) {
    label = randomString();
  }
  return label;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
  let label = generateRandomLabel();
  console.log(label);
}
```